# ID duplication when persisting events (event sourcing)

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

Applying domain driven design I read about event sourcing. That saves a stream of events. The event table of database has these columns:

```
EventID, EventDate, AggregateId, EventData
```

I can save **product, category** and **order** events in this table. But `aggregateId` may be duplicated. In this situation I will get order event as product event.

How can I prevent duplication of system Id.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, an Aggregate Root has a globally unique identifier.  If you are doing DDD (and I assume you are since you tagged the question with DDD), and you are using event sourcing to capture an Aggregate Root's event stream, then you will need to find a way to ensure uniqueness across different aggregate types.

You can either generate a GUID or use some sort of composite key as others have suggested.

Comment: See also: Named UUID.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just make the AggregateID a composite key of type and id? so you can have `Product:123456` and `Category:123456`? Or you could add another column for aggregate type if thats a better solution for you.

Comment: I would add another column.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using a client side generated GUID, I would recommend adding a few columns to the table.

```
EventID, EventType, EventDate, AggregateType, AggregateId, MetaData, EventData
```

I would add the event type and the aggregate type for several reasons.
They will support rehydration of the underlying types, allow additional indexes on the table, and represent rather important information in the system. Finally it likely simplifies the read query on the table avoiding a couple of joins.

The metadata will allow tracking user and/or source event information.

Even though this adds the information to make it possible I would avoid using a composite key, stick with the GUID keys.

If you can't use a client side GUID then newsequentialguid() on the EventID as a primary key is the way to go.